# Users to post a comment in my website

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want users to post a comment in my website.
I have already made a textarea box where users can post comment and see the commment on the same page using jQuery.
But at a time only one user can post on comment.

My website is in JSP.

i want users to post as many comment as they can and while loading page i want to show the comments made by other user.

Comment: Which module? You haven't shown much of a code that resembles a module. How do you expect someone suggesting you to enhance something that you don't show?

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer using a third party plugin instead of hammering out a home-brewed guestbook, I would suggest **[flexi comment](http://flexicommentbox.alimsyed.com)** thingie...
it is simply the easiest way of getting a nice comment scene going on your website!

Comment: I don't know about the original poster of this question, but I ended up using Flexi Comment Box for my HTML website and seems to deliver - at least for the time being we haven't found anything that doesn't work... but lets hope it stays that way :D  but none the less, an excellent find!

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the trouble of building it yourself.  Or you could use a third party resource like Disqus.

If your going to build it yourself, you'll need to use more than just a text area.  You will need some sort of repeating control that displays each individual comment wrapped in some sort of html container like a div.  Your jsp page will have to build these controls and append them to the dom dynamically at page load.

Personally, I'd go for a third party resource.

Comment: +1 Disqus is probably the easiest method for the OP to get what they are after.